# swagger documentation for endpoint with url pattern

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I want to create swagger documentation for an endpoint with ** pattern. In swagger-ui page I find the endpoint but there isn't any input for url of **. My endpoint signature is:

```
@GetMapping("/{category}/**")
public DocumentModel fetch(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathVariable("category") String category)
```

I want to call above endpoint by myCategory/test/document1 address but there isn't any placeholder for test/document1. How can I call this endpoint by swagger?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not doable. Swagger supports neither wildcards in the path, nor optional path segments, nor slashes in path parameter values. If you look at the request that swagger-ui executes for your mapping, you will see something like this:

```sh
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/category1/**"
```

The stars are not replaced, they are treated as a normal string, not as a placeholder.

I am afraid your only option is modifying the endpoint or adding a new one, e.g:

```java
@GetMapping("/{category}/test/{document}")
@Parameter(name = "document", in = ParameterIn.PATH)
public DocumentModel fetchTest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathVariable("category") String category) {
    return fetch(httpServletRequest, category);
}

@GetMapping("/{category}/**")
public DocumentModel fetch(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathVariable("category") String category) {
    // ...
}
```

If you need to, you can hide the original endpoint from the swagger-ui:

```java
@GetMapping("/{category}/**")
@Operation(hidden = true)
public DocumentModel fetch(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathVariable("category") String category) {
    // ...
}
```